# Invalid session token (code: 209) XCode Swift

Tags: parse-platform

I've added the line of code

[PFUser enableRevocableSessionInBackground]

right under the Parse initialization code, but it gives me some errors. First it tells me to put a separator after PFUser

[PFUser, enableRevocableSessionInBackground]

but the next error says

Use of unresolved identifier 'enableRevocableSessionInBackground'

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you download the updated SDK from Parse.com and replace the older one you had in your app with the new one?  From what I'm seeing it isn't recognising that statement, because it was introduced in a later SDK version.

Comment: Hmm I just started using Parse yesterday, so I assume I have the latest one.

Comment: Oh sorry, when you said legacy I assumed your app had used parse before, but without revocable sessions

Comment: Well technically, I think it did? I ran my app, added a user successfully, then when I tried it again, I had that error that said something about invalid session token (code: 209). Then I'm now here trying to add that line from above.